# Difference between this and var in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class that I'm creating. This class has private and public functions/properties. My understanding of private and public was that `this` was public  and `var` was private to that function and its members. However, within the local function `buildFramework()`, when I call the `var settings.currentView` I get the error:

> `settings.currentView` is not defined

My question is, what is the difference between `this` and `var` in the scope of a function and its members as well as the global scope?

```
namespace('example');
example.InstagramViewer = function (options) {
    // this works when called within buildFramework()
    this.settings = $.extend({
        currentView: 'grid'
    }, options);

    // this doesn't work when called within buildFramework()
    var settings = $.extend({
        currentView: 'grid'
    }, options);

    var viewer;

    this.init = function () {
        buildFramework();
    };

    var buildFramework = function() {
        viewer = $(viewerWrapper).append('<div id="instagramViewer" class="' + settings.currentView + '"></div>'); // this doesn't work
        viewer = $(viewerWrapper).append('<div id="instagramViewer" class="' + this.settings.currentView + '"></div>'); // this does work
    };
}
```

and called like so...

```
$(function () {
    var viewer = new connectionsAcademy.publicWebsite.web.js.teenWebsite.InstagramViewer();
    viewer.init();
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you instancing a new object?

Comment: I think you are confused about which line works, and which doesn't. `this.settings.currentView` shouldn't work in that context, `this` would be the global object (window).

Comment: @bfavaretto updated my question above to answer yours :)

Comment: @bfavaretto `this` is in the scope of `InstagramViewer = function(options){}`

Comment: @bfavaretto it works because settings is declared with `this.settings` and thus the exexution context does not matter.

Comment: @bflemi3 you are misunderstanding the keyword `this` - it is not per default attached to the function itself, but it depends on the execution context which object is attached to `this`.

Comment: @bflemi3 Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/G5qYA/. `this` will be window in that case. It would be your object if `createFramework` were "public".

Comment: After `InstagramViewer.init` calls `buildFramework`, `this` is `Window` and `Window.settings` does not exist. It's not the `settings.currentView` that fails, but the `this.settings.currentView`.

Comment: I see that now. Thank you very much for the jsfiddle bfavaretto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of differences here.

First, 'this' is a keyword which is a reference to the calling object. If you call your function as is, the window will be the calling object and you are setting a global variable by using the the keyword 'this'.

```
InstagramViewer();
console.log(window.settings);
```

However, if you call your function through another object, window will no longer be the calling object and instead of setting a global variable you will be setting a member variable on that object.

```
var obj = {InstagramViewer: InstagramViewer};
obj.InstagramViewer();
console.log(obj.settings);
```

using 'var' in both these cases makes no difference. 'var' works different then 'this' because it affects no object besides what we will call the function's scratchpad. Only the function can access its scratchpad (unless you create some kind of closure which exposes a variable on this scratch pad). This is why you can think of a variable defined with 'var' as being private.

using 'var' is also different then 'this' when dealing with 'delete'. 'delete' will not work on a variable declared with 'var', but it will when defining a variable on 'this' or any other object.

```
var F = function() {
    this.foo = 'foo';
    var bar = 'bar';

    delete(bar);
    delete(this.foo);

    alert(bar);
    alert(this.foo);
};


F();
```

My explanation is crude, but this is a big subject that can not be easily explained in this context. I highly recommend you read this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000486.do. Especially chapter 7.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding of private and public was that this was public and var was private to that function and its members

That's incorrect.

`var <variable_name>` declares variable with correspondent name in the current scope. You cannot write `var foo.bar` because `foo.bar` is incorrect variable name.

`this.name` - it's accessing the property `name` of the object `this`

Comment: but why can't `buildFramework()` access `var settings`? Isn't that still considered in the same scope?

Comment: @bflemi3: it can. `settings` variable is passed as a closure there. http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/keXcm/

Comment: Sorry, can you explain further? Is it because `buildFramework()` returns a function? If I changed it to `function buildFramework()` would that change things?

Comment: @bflemi3: would that change what? Have you opened the jsfiddle? `settings` variable *is* available from `buildFramework()`

Answer (score 0):

If you just define functions within the closure of the object, they're "private". You can make them publicly available by adding them as an attribute to the object itself:

```
function ObjectWithPrivateFunction() {

  var _privateVariable = 0;

  function _privateFunction(someValue) {
    _privateVariable = someValue;
  } // _privateFunction()

  this.publicAccessToPrivateFunction = _privateFunction;

} // ObjectWithPrivateFunction()
```

Comment: Yes, this I understand. What is stumping me is why `settings.currentView` throws an error but `this.settings.currentView` works

Comment: @bflemi3: "throws an error" because `var settings.currentView` is syntactically incorrect

Comment: the line that's being called is... `viewer = $(viewerWrapper).append('<div id="instagramViewer" class="' + settings.currentView + '"></div>');`. That's not incorrect right? That's throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

1) You are confusing `scope` and `context`.
2) Unlike other languages, `this` is mutable - it depends on the caller to which object it is bound.
3) There is no "private" or "public" in javascript: there are only objectproperties which are always public and variable which are restricted to the scope of the enclosing function. Consider the following example:

```
var object = {
    x:10,
    func: function(){
        var x = 1;
        console.log(x, this.x);
    }
}
```

`object.func();` will now output `1` and `10` because both `x` do coexist - the one as property of the element `object` - this is the context, the other `x` is a variable restricted to the scope of it's enclosing function.

You are doing the same - you are creating a property on the `this` object (Also very important - `this` is mutable, depending on how the function is called) and then trying to access a variable `setting` with a property `currentView` which will fail, because JS checks the scope but doesn't find the according variable.

Answer (score -1):

Very loosely speaking, the keyword `this` is more like a public class where `var` is strictly private.

For example,

```
function testPublic(str)
{
    this.getTHIS=function()
                 {
                     alert(str)
                 }
}

function testPrivate(str)
{
    var getTHIS=function()
                {
                    alert(str);
                }
}


//now run the code
new testPublic('hello there').getTHIS(); //alert hello there
```

However, for the second one, you cannot access getTHIS function from outside the parent function